# Serving Multiple Vue Pages Using Express?

Tags: express, vuejs3

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using Vue.js for the frontend and Express for the backend. My goal is to serve multiple Vue pages through Express, but I'm unsure about the best approach to achieve this.

So far, I've been able to serve a single page using

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist')));
```

but I need guidance on how to extend this to serve multiple pages. My goal is to have a separate login-page. Creating a vue project for every page, building it and then serving the needed `/dist` seems somewhat stressful and probably unnecessary. Can anyone provide a clear and concise solution or point me in the right direction? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my `server.js`:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// enable CORS
app.use(cors());

// accept body in json-format for requests
app.use(express.json());

// parse forms and json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: true }));

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist')));

// connect to Mongo-DB if it exists, else create it
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', (err) => console.error(err));
db.on('disconnected', () => console.log('Disconnected from database...'));
db.once('connected', () => console.log('Connected to database...'));

// Every route `127.0.0.1/clubs/...` is bound to `clubRouter`
const clubRouter = require('./routes/tables');
app.use('/tables', clubRouter);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).json({ ERROR: err.message })
});

const port = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`));
```

Thank you.

Comment: I’d recommend a Vue tutorial. They’re normally delivered as SPAs.